# Refresh an item of ListView

Tags: flutter, listviewitem, flutter-listview

I have a problem to refresh my ListView. I manage to modify my item, but after the pop it does not update, and I have to exit and return to the page to see the modification.

In my UserInfoCard, the background is grey if the user have a deletedAt not null.

When I see my item of list after pressed button OK, my user is always enabled. I exit/return to the page and my user disabled and the background is grey.

```
class UserListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserListPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserListPageState createState() => _UserListPageState();
}

class _UserListPageState extends State<UserListPage> {
  late UserApi _api;
  late User userSelected;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _api = UserApi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _api.getUsers(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<User>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
              child: Text(
                  "Something wrong with message: ${snapshot.error.toString()}"));
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          List<User> users = snapshot.data!;
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: MyToolBar(),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: _buildListView(users)),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView(List<User> list) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 8.0, horizontal: DEFAULT_PADDING),
        child: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              User item = list[index];
              return Slidable(
                key: const ValueKey(0),
                startActionPane: ActionPane(
                  motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                  children: _buildSlidableAction(context, item),
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                      context, Routes.admUserForm,
                      arguments: {"fenType": FenType.read, "user": item}),
                  child: UserInfoCard(
                      pseudo: item.pseudo!,
                      familyName: item.familyName,
                      resume: item.resume,
                      avatar: item.avatar,
                      deletedAt: item.deletedAt),
                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: list.length,
          ),
        ));
  }

  List<SlidableAction> _buildSlidableAction(BuildContext context, User item) {
    bool isDesactived = (item.deletedAt != null) ? false : true;
    return [
      SlidableAction(
          onPressed: (context) {
            userSelected = item;
            _showDialog();
          },
          backgroundColor:
              isDesactived ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.lightGreen,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          icon: isDesactived
              ? Icons.do_not_disturb_outlined
              : Icons.check_circle_outline_outlined),
      SlidableAction(
          onPressed: (context) => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
              context, Routes.admUserForm,
              arguments: {"fenType": FenType.update, "user": item}),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          icon: Icons.edit),
    ];
  }

  void Function() koButtonPressed() => () {
        Navigator.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!).pop(false);
      };
  void Function() okButtonPressed() => () {
        setState(() {
          late SnackBar snackBar;
          bool isDesactived = (userSelected.deletedAt != null) ? false : true;
          User userDisabled = userSelected;

          userDisabled.deletedAt = isDesactived ? DateTime.now() : null;
          _api.disabled(userDisabled).then((value) {
            if (value) {
              String message = isDesactived ? 'User disabled' : 'User enabled';
              snackBar = MyWidget.okSnackBar(message);
              userSelected.deletedAt = userDisabled.deletedAt;
            } else {
              String message =
                  isDesactived ? 'Don\'t User disabled' : 'Don\'t User enabled';
              snackBar = MyWidget.koSnackBar(message);
            }
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          });
          Navigator.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!).pop();
        });
      };

  void _showDialog() {
    bool enable = (userSelected.deletedAt == null) ? true : false;
    String pseudo = userSelected.pseudo!;
    String title = enable ? "Disable" : "Enable";
    String message = enable ? "Disable $pseudo ?" : "Enable $pseudo ?";
    String textKoButton = "Cancel";
    String textOkButton = enable ? "Disable" : 'Enable';

    MyDialog alert = MyDialog(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        onPressedKo: koButtonPressed(),
        onPressedOk: okButtonPressed(),
        textKoButton: textKoButton,
        textOkButton: textOkButton);

    showDialog(
      context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
      builder: (BuildContext context1) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `SetState` in your function in which you are updating an item of your list and check if it works or not. Maybe the build function is not executing that is why your state is not changing while you stay on screen.

Comment: Thanks I resolve this in update `setState` in my function okButtonPressed() for 
            `setState(() {
              userSelected.deletedAt = userDisabled.deletedAt;
            });`